# Teamd cannot be run as root?

Tags: linux, networking, systemd, gentoo

```
teamd -d
This program is not intended to be run as root.
```

First of all, I'd like confirmation that the configuration teamd does is actually system-wide.

Second of all, I'd like to know how that's even possible.

Third of all, I'd like to know how unprivileged users having control over the network interfaces isn't a massive security hazard.

Fourth of all, I'd like to know how I'm supposed to ensure that teamd is running before processes from other users are started that might depend on it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `teamd` doesn't run when run from a root shell and is instead meant to be run through `sudo` as stated in the [tutorial](https://github.com/jpirko/libteam/wiki/Tutorial).

> Now, you can just run teamd without any configuration file:
>
> `$ sudo teamd -d`

This of course means that it does run as root.

Comment: That's a new one. I'll have to install sudo tomorrow to check. How am I supposed to ensure that teamd is running before any users are logged in?

Comment: What are you installing it on?

Comment: What OS? Gentoo/systemd.